# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL

Tags: php, json, ssl

estoy usando una API de TheMovieDB para extraer información de los episodios de Juego de tronos. pero me sale un error *file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed*

Yo usaba la API normal hasta que hoy me sale este error.

Aquí está mi código PHP

```
<?php

$json=json_decode(getSSLPage('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399/season/1/episode/1?api_key=e671ab8a71b766baa34fb3cde66861b3&language=es-ES'));

echo $json->still_path;
echo $json->name;

?>
```

Comment: Y el codigo getSSLPage ?

Comment: No lo tengo. Ya hay una respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta pasar la siguiente configuracion al file_get_contents

```
 <?php
    
    
    $arrContextOptions=array(
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );  
    
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399/season/1/episode/1?api_key=e671ab8a71b766baa34fb3cde66861b3&language=es-ES", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    
    echo $response;
```